# Ansible creates directory in the control machine even if delegate_to set to remote when running the playbook with local connection

Tags: ansible

I'm running an ansible-playbook configured to provision ec2 and configure the machine. I set the connection to local for the playbook because no machine to manage before the script runs. Once provisioned, I supposed to create directory in the remote server. Since the playbook runs in local connection, I set to delete_to: {{ remote_host }} so this directory creation executed in remote host but it still creates the directory in the control machine.

```
- name: provision instance for Apache
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars/env.yml
  vars:
    allow_world_readable_tmpfiles: true
    key_name: ansible-test
    region: us-east-2
    image: ami-0e82959d4ed12de3f # Ubuntu 18.04
    id: "practice-akash-ajay"
    sec_group: "{{ id }}-sec"
    remote_host: ansible-test
    remaining_days: 20
    acme_directory: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # acme_directory: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    cert_name: "{{ app_slug }}.{{ app_domain}}"
    intermediate_path: /etc/pki/letsencrypt/intermediate.pem
    cert:
      common_name: "{{ app_slug }}.{{ app_domain}}"
      organization_name: PearlThoughts
      email_address: "{{ letsencrypt_email }}"
      subject_alt_name:
      - "DNS:{{ app_slug }}.{{ app_domain}}"
  roles:
    - aws
```

```
- name: Create certificate storage directory
  file:
    dest: "{{item.path}}"
    mode: 0750
    state: directory
  delegate_to: {{ remote_host }}
  with_items:
  - path: ~/lets-seng-test
```

Comment: The task option is `delegate_to` not `delete_to`, but I don't see either of those in your playbook/task.

Comment: Thanks, I checked my playbooks, it has set to delegate_to. I fixed the typo in both title and description, still the same results. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `connection` explicitly on the play, it will be used for all tasks in that play. So don't do that. Ansible will by default use a `local` connection for `localhost` unless you have explicitly changed that in your inventory (and again, don't do that).

If you remove the `connection` setting on your play, `delegate_to` might work the way you expect...but I don't think you want to do that.

If you have your playbook provisioning a new host for you, the way to target that host with Ansible is to have a new play with that host (or it's corresponding group) listed in the target `hosts:` for the play.  Conceptually, you want:

```
- host: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: provisiong an AWS instance
      aws_ec2: [...]
      register: hostinfo

    - add_host:
        name: myhost
        ansible_host: "{{ hostinfo... }}"

- hosts: myhost
  tasks:
    - name: do something on the new host
      command: uptime
```

You probably need some logic in between provisioning the host and executing tasks against it to ensure that it is up and ready to service requests.

Instead of using the `add_host` module, a better solution is often to rely on the appropriate inventory plugin.

Comment: I'm getting closer. I mentioned host to localhost in the playbook.yml hence the all the tasks were constrained to localhost. Changing to `all` appears to pick the delegate_to host but it still picks the control machine. I have configured ansible-test in my ~/.ssh directory and also added it to the inventory so I have no clue.

Having separate hosts look clean but I have to mix both local and remote actions, hence preferred delegate_to. Is it what the purpose of delegate_to?

Comment: That is a purpose of `delegate_to`, yes. If you want to update your question to include the specific tasks you're trying to accomplish we might be able to provide you with a better answer.

Comment: I'm simply trying to create a directory in the remote host but it keeps creating in control machine (My Mac). Pls check the task in the question

Comment: If we put connection: local, it would expect all hosts to have 127.0.0.1. I had to remove it to make it work. I plan to mention delegate_to in all tasks either localhost and remote until I figure out a solution

https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/orchestration/ansible/devel/usage/connection-local-or-delegate-to.html

Comment: Removing connection: local makes everything running in a remote host. I need to have 90% of the tasks running in local but few to be done in the remote host. Is there a way to run all tasks in local and selectively execute tasks in the remote host?